# Vimdiff: How to put all changes inside a particular function from one file to another?

Tags: linux, vim, diff, vimdiff

In Vimdiff, I know I can use "do" or "dp" to move changes from one file to the other...but these are for individual changes. If I have to undo all changes inside a specific scope/selection (say undo all changes to a particular function, but leave the rest untouched), is there a way to do it in one go ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a visual selection and the ex command `:diffget`/`:diffput`

So, for example to get the changes for just the current insides of a code block ( { ... } )

```
Vi}:diffget<Enter>
```

To *put* the changes for the two enclosing levels including the lines with the brackets:

```
V2a}:diffput<Enter>
```

Note that since these are ex commands the motions are linewise. Of course, you could use any range, so you can repeat the visual range, or use markers

```
:'a,'bdiffput
```

etc. Use your imagination, this is vim :)

Comment: Great answer - not only did u nail the question, you showed me a different way to visually select a block !!

Comment: +1 for teaching me that I can do `diffput` and `diffget` on ranges. Also, it would've never occur to me to use `diffput` and `diffget` for selective _undo_, guess my imagination kinda sucks... :)